# Sass/JQuery - Dynamic url for image

Tags: javascript, jquery, sass

I have the following style on my page:

```css
  div#mockUp {
    @include fancy-container(
      $background-image:
        url("../../assets/images/mock-ups/minimalist-profile-en.png"),
      $height: auto,
      $min-height: 95vh
    );
  }
```

And this JS script:

```js
/**
 * Gets the device's browser language.
 *
 * @memberof module:i18n/Functions
 * @function getNavigatorLanguage
 * @returns {string | undefined} The language of the browser
 */
export default () => navigator.language ?? navigator.userLanguage;
```

I want to change the url of the #mockUp container based on the user language.

For example, if the user's lang is spanish, then the url should be "../../assets/images/mock-ups/minimalist-profile-es.png".

Can this be done with sass only? Should I use JQuery instead?

Comment: You probably don't need the JS script if you have a `lang` attribute on the `<html>` tag. You could use it in your css `html[lang="es"] .mySuperSelector {...}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from Sass, by adding an additional class to `div#mockup` like

```
<div id="#mockUp" class="lang-es" ..
```

And if the element has the class `lang-es`, include a different `background-image`:

```
div#mockUp {
    @include fancy-container(
        $background-image:
           url("../../assets/images/mock-ups/minimalist-profile-en.png"),
        $height: auto,
        $min-height: 95vh
    );
    &.lang-es { 
        @include fancy-container(
            $background-image:
            url("../../assets/images/mock-ups/minimalist-profile-en.es"),
            $height: auto,
            $min-height: 95vh
        );
    }
}
```